# Custom Taxonomy and tax_query Issue?

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, wp-query, custom-taxonomy

I am working on Plugin development and my plugin name is `plugindev`.I have a custom post type called `team`.I have a custom taxonomy `Team_Category` which is being registered by this code

```
/***************************taxonomy****************************/
add_action( 'init', 'create_team_taxonomies', 0 );
function create_team_taxonomies() {
    // Add new taxonomy, make it hierarchical (like categories)
    $labels = array(
        'name'              => _x( 'Team_Categories', 'taxonomy general name' ),
        'singular_name'     => _x( 'Team_Category', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
        'search_items'      => __( 'Search Team_Categories' ),
        'all_items'         => __( 'All Team_Categories' ),
        'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Team_Category' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Team_Category:' ),
        'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Team_Category' ),
        'update_item'       => __( 'Update Team_Category' ),
        'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Team_Category' ),
        'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Team_Category Name' ),
        'menu_name'         => __( 'Team_Category' ),
    );

    $args = array(
        'hierarchical'      => true,
        'labels'            => $labels,
        'show_ui'           => true,
        'show_admin_column' => false,
        'query_var'         => true,
        'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => 'Team_Category' ),
    );

    register_taxonomy( 'Team_Category', array( 'team' ), $args );
}
/****************************taxanomy end***********************************/
```

But when I use a tax_query in my WP_Query, I do  not get any  posts.
here is my code

```
<?php
$taxonomy_name = 'Team_Category';
$get_categories = get_terms($taxonomy_name);
$total_categories = count($get_categories);
// Loop through the obituaries:
for ($i = 0; $i < $total_categories; $i++) {
    ?>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <?php echo $category_name = $get_categories[$i]->name; ?>
        </div>
        <?php
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'team',
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'Team_Category', 
                    'field' => 'slug', 'terms' => $category_name,)
                )
         );

        $query = new WP_Query($args);

        if ($query->have_posts()) {
        while ($query->have_posts()) {
            $query->the_post();
            the_title();
        }
        }
        wp_reset_query(); ?>

    </div>

<?php }
```

It works perfectly without `tax_query`.I did lot of google but found no suitable result.Any solution to solve this problem .Any help would be highly  appreciated

Comment: What happens if you wrap your `$category_name` in an array()? Like so: `'terms' => array( $category_name )`.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee  Nothing happens still same situation...

Comment: it seems like the code is fine. I copied / pasted it and I didn't have a problem with it. Are you certain that the category has posts attached to it?

Comment: @Howdy_McGee  as i have pasted this question in stack overflow  where I got its solution by using `'taxonomy' => 'team_category','terms' => $category_name,` and changing `Team_Category` to `team_category`.. but I don't know why this code is not running `'tax_query' => array(array( 'taxonomy' => 'team_category', 'field' => 'slug', 'terms' =>$category_name))` even i have changed  `Team_Category` to `team_category`

Comment: I used the capitalization and didn't run into an issue. Maybe break your code into bits to ensure you're getting the expected data. `print_r( $get_categories );` before the loop to ensure your terms are in there. Mayb remove your `WP_Query` from the `for` loop and pass in a string slug that you know has posts assigned to it to ensure your `WP_Query` works.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is right in your code, but it's really easy to overlook. Let's take a closer look at this part:

```
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <?php echo $category_name = $get_categories[$i]->name; ?>
    </div>
    <?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'team',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'Team_Category', 
                'field' => 'slug', 'terms' => $category_name
            )
        )
    );
```

What exactly is going on in here? You get name of term and store it as `$category_name` (`$category_name = $get_categories[$i]->name;`).

Later, you use this value as a slug (`'field' => 'slug', 'terms' => $category_name`).

Slug and name are different things, so there is a really big probability that your Tax_Query won't find anything (if name contains capital letter, space or any special character, slug will be different from name).

So it should work fine, if you'll change it so it looks like this:

```
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <?php echo $get_categories[$i]->name; ?>
    </div>
    <?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'team',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'Team_Category', 
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $get_categories[$i]->slug;
            )
        )
    );

    $query = new WP_Query($args);
```